# Adding users to a PFRelation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a "friends" system in my app, and when the user accepts a friend request, I add both users to a relation like this:

```
var cUserRelation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("friendsRelation") as PFRelation
var senderRelation = sender.relationForKey("friendsRelation") as PFRelation

cUserRelation.addObject(sender)
senderRelation.addObject(PFUser.currentUser())

PFUser.currentUser.saveInBackground()
sender.saveInBackground()
```

but for some reason it adds the sender to the relation only for the current user. How can I fix that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample project from treehouse that might be helpful:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:nil];


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// if the current relationKey doesn't exist, it will be create for us.
PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendsRelation"];
// adding users is easy. use addObject methoed then we can pass in the user that was tapped on as the parameter. To get that user, we have to get the indexPath just like we did in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method
PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([self isFriend:user])
{

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    // 2. remove from the array of friends // the only way we have to find a user in an array is to loop through and look for a matching objectid.
    for (PFUser *friend in self.friends)
    {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId])
        {
            [self.friends removeObject:friend];
            break;
        }
    // 3. Remove from the backend
        [friendsRelation removeObject:user];
        [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }];
    }
}
    else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.friends addObject:user];
    for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
            [self.friends addObject:friend];
            break;
        }

        // and now we can use the user variable here as the parameter for addObject, which adds the user locally
        [friendsRelation addObject:user];
        // but we also have to add the user on the backend
        [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];


    }
}
}
```